# Understanding a nested Conditional (ternary) operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

**Check if One Array can be Nested in Another using a Ternary Operator**

> Create a function that returns true if the first array can be nested
> inside the second.
>
> arr1 can be nested inside arr2 if:
>
> arr1's min is greater than arr2's min. arr1's max is less than arr2's
> max.

Comment: What has this question to do with the ternary/conditional operator?

Answer (score -1):

Below is the function used based on the provided guide.

```js
function canNest(arr1, arr2) {
     // arr1's min is greater than arr2's min.
     // arr1's max is less than arr2's max
     return (Math.min(...arr1) > Math.min(...arr2) ? (Math.max(...arr1) < Math.max(...arr2) ? true: false) : false);

}

console.log(canNest([1, 2, 3, 4],[0, 6]));
console.log(canNest([3, 1], [4, 0]));
console.log(canNest([9, 9, 8], [8, 9]));
console.log(canNest([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3]));
```

Below is the guide I used to write nested conditional operators or functions.

[image: nested statement guide]

Comment: Just use a regular `if ... else ...`